# Rails - Combining Variables and Saving them in the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "Word" model that has 3 string variables: "word_a" , "word_b" , "word_ab".

A form in my view collects the values for "word_a" and "word_b":

```
  <%= f.text_field :word_a %>
  <%= f.text_field :word_b %>
```

What is the best way to save the value for "word_ab" which will be made automatically from a combo of "word_a" and "word_b"?

The way Im doing it now seems really really wrong. After submitting the first form, I have the controller redirect to another edit page with a 'word_ab' form that has a value that combines 'word_a' and 'word_b'.

```
  <%= f.text_field :word_ab, :value => @word.word_a+"_"+@word.word_b %>
```

The user then has to resubmit the form to save 'word_ab' into the database.  Can't I do this is a controller?

Comment: Yes I believe you've answered your own question.  Just do the combination in the submit action in the controller.  Then just store this in your data store

Comment: Thanks Nuclear.  So is that the best way to do it? A multi-step form?

Comment: Sorry Nuclear. I read that wrong.  What would the code in the controller look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to save concated value to db? What about editing?

If you still want to do it - best idea is to add attr_accessor in model

```
attr_accessible :word_a, :word_b
attr_accessor :word_a, :word_b
```

First line allows yo perform mass assign, second one creates setter and getter methods.
Then, still in a model do

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  self.word_ab = word_a + word_b
end
```

You may perform this on `before_save` as well, and you may validate `word_a` and `word_b` separately with regular validators.

Pro tip: create getter method that returns concated string

```
def word_ab
  self.word_a + self.word_b
end
```

Associated models

```
class User
  has_one :profile_picture

  def word_ab
    self.profile_picture.url + self.word_a + self.word_b
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  That worked perfectly.  Although you do bring up a good point about editing that will cause me to rethink the approach a bit. Is it possible to bring a variable from another model into the 'word_ab' variable?  For example:    self.word_ab = @picture.name + word_a + word_b ?

Comment: Yeah, it's always easy to merge strings, harder to split them, see updated answer for a tip.

Comment: Yes, if it is associated model. I would not recommend referring to not associated models, it would be a bad design.

Comment: It's associated so it works well.  Thanks again.  One issue that I encountered though was that when I had "attr_accessible :word_a, :word_b  attr_accessor :word_a, :word_b", word_a and word_b wouldnt save but word_ab would. I removed attr_accessor entirely and everything works perfectly.  Not sure though why.

Comment: because `attr_accessor` was overriding setter and getter behaviour